# Thread termination in Symbian

Tags: symbian

I'm getting a little frustrated with the definition of Thread Termination they have in Symbian. Please, correct me if I am wrong. Threads in Symbian OS can end their life in 4 different ways:

1. When thread function exits normally;
2. When User::Exit() is called for current thread;
3. When thread is forced to die by calling RThread::Kill() or RThread::Terminate();
4. When panic has been raised on the thread by User::Panic

My question is: which one of these four situations corresponds to 'thread termination'?

PS: I came up with this question when while exploring "critical threads" definition in Symbian documentation. Maybe this [extract](http://library.forum.nokia.com/topic/S60_5th_Edition_Cpp_Developers_Library/GUID-35228542-8C95-4849-A73F-2B4F082F0C44/sdk/doc_source/reference/reference-cpp/Kernel_Architecture_2/UserClass.html#%3a%3aUser%3a%3aTCritical) could be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of them. The [SDK documentation](http://library.forum.nokia.com/topic/S60_5th_Edition_Cpp_Developers_Library/GUID-35228542-8C95-4849-A73F-2B4F082F0C44/sdk/doc_source/guide/Base-subsystem-guide/e32/ThreadAndProcessManagement/ThreadsAndProcesses/ThreadTermination.guide.html?resultof=%22%74%68%72%65%61%64%20%74%65%72%6d%69%6e%61%74%69%6f%6e%22%20) specifies it quite exactly:

> The death of a thread (and any
>   subsequent notifications etc.) is
>   effectively just an indication that
>   the thread will never execute any more
>   code; it does not guarantee that the
>   operating system has yet finished
>   removing the thread.

Now, if you're inspecting `RThread::ExitType`, you'll find the following information:

> `EExitKill` The thread or process has ended as a result of a kill, i.e. `Kill()` has been called on the `RThread` or `RProcess` handle. Or a thread was ended as a result of calling `User::Exit()`.
>
> `EExitTerminate` The thread or process has ended as a result of a terminate, i.e. `Terminate()` has been called on the `RThread` or `RProcess` handle.
>
> `EExitPanic` The thread or process has been panicked.
>
> `EExitPending` The thread or process is alive.

For cases 1, 2 and `Kill` in case 3, you'll get `EExitKill`. Other cases are quite self-explanatory.

Comment: >>> For cases 1, 2 and Kill in case 3, you'll get EExitKill

Should this be true, than it would be impossible to determine if thread has died normally - though thread function exit. Which is crucial, because in case of abnormal termination thread resources are not disposed properly.

Comment: Kill is a normal termination; Terminate is abnormal.

Comment: SDK documentation states that there are no difference between them - just logical, Kill is a nice guy, while Terminate is a mean one. Difference appears only in ExitType category.

Comment: And no matter with method is called Kill or Terminate - resources are not disposed properly.